# Advantages and disadvantages of log to txt files in Android

Tags: android, logging

I am implementing Log information in Native Android App -

I've two way to implement this -

Way 1. To create a Log.txt file in SDCARD and store all Log info in Log.txt file

Way 2. Log.d("TAG" "string") and print all into console.

```
I'm following Way 1.
```

My Question here is  -

Q1. What is the adv & disadv of way 1 & 2

Q2. What is the best approch/practice to capture log info.

thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding:

Advantage

- single point of all log info,
- easy to manage,
- easy to delete (clear cache)
- performance (when file size grow up) performance of apps remain same

Disadvantage

- Anyone can read log file and can know which process is running onFile operation

Comment: is this an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Way 1:

> - Adv : Persistent
> - Disadv : More cumbersome, you'll have to manage opening file, preserving old content, closing properly, etc.

Way 2:

> - Adv : Easy to implement
> - Disadv : Not persistent

Console is good to track development of App and de-bugging purposes. If you're looking at logging content from multiple users and then somehow retrieving it to further process it, then go with Way 1, else, Way 2 should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Talking in general, is always a good idea to log to a text file as long *as is not too much output*. If your users encounter an error in your application, you can fetch the logs and see what went wrong. I really don't care if the users will read my log files, they can delete the file in worst case scenario, but casual users don't care to search for log files(do you?!).

If you log to console, it will be only for debugging, but you will get nothing for production mode because you cannot access user's console, do you?

Android doesn't seem to be different, log files are usually small for small applications and you can even keep it small for bigger apps(keep last X lines).

My 0.02$